# Where does Puma log to

Tags: ruby, logging, webserver, thin, puma

I have been using Thin to run my ruby Sinatra applications but I am now switching over to Puma. Thin creates its own log `log/thin.log` which I use. I noticed that Puma doesn't produce a log file (not that I can see). I have tried googling for documentation around this but not really found anything.

I was wondering if/how you can specify a log path in Puma.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the example [config.rb](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb#L49) as recommended on the repo's [README](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/README.md).

As shown there:

```
# Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to files specified. The 3rd parameter
# (“append”) specifies whether the output is appended, the default is “false”.


stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr'
stdout_redirect '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stdout', '/u/apps/lolcat/log/stderr', true
```

Comment: Is it possible to redirect to a logger (an object) instead of a file?

Comment: I had the same question as @yegor256. I used a hack to make it working by adding following to my config
`log = Syslog::Logger.new 'my_app'; log_formatter { |s| log.info s; s }`.